# Is there such a thing as relativistic maneuver?

Tags: relativistic-rocket

Specially for a fast probe to alpha centauri, where two massive bodies are available, is there a calculation of how many degrees can a relativistic body turn using these bodies, depending of the speed?

Comment: You can find some of the relevant mathematics here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/772180/123208 although that question is about a single compact body, i.e., a black hole or neutron star, where the trajectory can get within a few Schwarzschild radii of the massive body. However, you don't get much deflection of relativistic trajectories near normal stars. Eg, a light beam grazing the Sun gets deflected by ~1.75 arc-seconds. So it's not much use in a braking manoeuvre.

Comment: I think this is relevant too https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/478225/maximum-scattering-angle-for-relativistic-elastic-collision